# Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part version

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, datastax

I am working on a spring application to insert an record to datastax cassandra using spring.
Below is my the script used to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE user(
            name text,
            source text,
            createddate timestamp,
            version timestamp,
            id timeuuid,
            system text,
            desc text,
            PRIMARY KEY((name,source,createddate),version)
);
```

Below is the dto i have written to connect to cassandra table.

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class User implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String name; 
@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String source; 
@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 2,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private Date createddate; 
@PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 3,type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
private Date version; 
private UUID id;
private String system;
private String desc;
```

But when I try to insert the record, it is throwing the exception "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part version". Please help me out in this issue. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1°) Have you checked the `version` field is not `null` ?

2°) As I've never used Spring Data for Cassandra I'm not sure but by looking at  [those annotations documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/mapping/package-summary.html) maybe you could :

- create a dedicated Primary Key class annotated with `@PrimaryKeyClass`
- put your `@PrimaryKeyColumn` annotated attributes in it
- use that fresh new primary key class in your `User` class, annotated with `@PrimaryKey`

Comment: Thanks ThSlyu. As said version feild was null. Now I assigned a value to it and it is working fine.